# Moving my store-bought Windows 8 Pro license off of old laptop to new laptop

Tags: windows-8, license-key

I have installed Windows 8 Pro onto laptop 1 from a CD purchased at a store.
I entered the CD key on Laptop 1.

Now laptop1 is out of commission, and I want to move my Windows 8 Pro license from dead laptop1 to fresh new shiny I7 laptop2.

I have installed Windows 8 Pro onto shiny laptop2, and then entered the CD key into the Windows activation feature screen, which changed the initially installed from CD version to Windows 8 Pro.

But the computer is saying it is not licensed - telling me to activate with a different key or buy a new one.

I just want to use the same activation key on the new computer as the old one.

Does anyone know how to deactivate Windows on dead laptop1 and use the key again on shiny laptop2?

Comment: The only solution that won't cost more money is to contact Microsoft and explain the problem to them. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-windows-activation-install-computer/

Comment: @IanAtkin why didnt you make this an aswer, i will accept it casue i am on the line with microsquish right now. using your help.

Comment: I have now. :) And you don't need to buy anything more from Microsoft. I've done this in the past and it worked out okay.

Comment: You may be able to simply install Windows 8 on another computer and use automated activation on the phone. Activation via phone also falls into *contacting Microsoft* category though. If you have a non-OEM license, you can move the license (and installation) to another computer.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov yea that is exactly what i ended up doing! worked like a long depressing dream.  had to call them three times casue there automated nu ber reading system is terrible.

Comment: @jordan.peoples I activated Windows two times using the automated system. They could read the numbers louder, the service did its job well. However, I felt slight confusion when I activated Windows via phone for the first time; the process was smoother on the second time.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I had my phone on speaker phone while the machine read the numbers, and it kept saying "Sorry i didnt catch that" even though the room was completely silent haha.  i think it was picking up my keystrokes on the laptop maybe and trying to interpret them as english lol

Comment: @jordan.peoples I didn't try to talk to it :) And it kept reading the numbers. Maybe they didn't implement voice recognition for Russian language and therefore didn't listen to what happens on the other side of the phone :))

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov You're a lucky man! haha :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution that won't cost more money is to contact Microsoft and explain the problem to them.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-windows-activation-install-computer/